# NextJs Render Erorrs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I receive the following errors when trying to build my page using "Yarn Build"

```
Automatically optimizing pages ...
Error occurred prerendering page "/design/des". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Cannot find module './des.md'

Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/po". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Cannot find module './po.md'

Error occurred prerendering page "/photo/pho". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Cannot find module './pho.md'

Error occurred prerendering page "/art/a". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Cannot find module './a.md'
```

I have tried running yarn upgrade to upgrade all modules, I have also looked through all of my files and nowhere in any pages are there any mentions of pho.md or any of the other listed items. Any idea on what might be causing these errors?

File Structure

```
package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── ArtList.js
│   │   ├── BlogList.js
│   │   ├── ContactForm.js
│   │   ├── DesignList.js
│   │   ├── Header.js
│   │   ├── Layout.js
│   │   ├── Meta.js
│   │   ├── PhotoList.js
│   │   ├── Singular.js
│   │   └── Social.js
│   ├── data
│   │   └── config.json
│   ├── markdown
│   │   ├── arts
│   │   │   ├── art1.md
│   │   │   ├── art2.md
│   │   │   └── art3.md
│   │   ├── design
│   │   │   ├── des1.md
│   │   │   ├── des2.md
│   │   │   └── des3.md
│   │   ├── photos
│   │   │   ├── 43qf.md
│   │   │   ├── 5 (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── 5.md
│   │   │   ├── a (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── a.md
│   │   │   ├── a#.md
│   │   │   ├── b (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── b.md
│   │   │   ├── c (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── dsfg (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── dsfg.md
│   │   │   ├── g.md
│   │   │   ├── photo-1 copy (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── photo-1 (copy).md
│   │   │   ├── photo-1 copy.md
│   │   │   ├── photo-1.md
│   │   │   ├── photo-2 copy (copy).md
│   │   │   └── photo-2 copy.md
│   │   └── posts
│   │       ├── cat-ipsum.md
│   │       └── cupkaes.md
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── about.js
│   │   ├── art
│   │   │   └── [slug].js
│   │   ├── art.js
│   │   ├── blog
│   │   │   └── [slug].js
│   │   ├── blog.js
│   │   ├── contact.js
│   │   ├── design
│   │   │   └── [slug].js
│   │   ├── design.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── music.js
│   │   ├── photo
│   │   │   └── [slug].js
│   │   └── photography.js
│   └── public
│       └── static
│           ├── art
│           │   ├── art1.jpg
│           │   └── art2.png
│           ├── design
│           │   ├── des1.jpg
│           │   └── des2.jpg
│           ├── fonts
│           │   └── photography
│           ├── main
│           │   ├── aboutimg.png
│           │   ├── click.png
│           │   ├── lucy.png
│           │   └── nextjs-black-logo.svg
│           ├── photo
│           │   ├── test2.jpg
│           │   ├── test3.jpg
│           │   ├── test4.jpg
│           │   ├── test.jpeg
│           │   └── test.jpg
│           └── post-img
│               ├── disenchantment.svg
│               └── dough.svg
└── yarn.lock
```

Full getStaticProps

```
export async function getStaticProps({ ...ctx }) {
  const { slug } = ctx.params
  const content = await import(`../../markdown/posts/${slug}.md`)
  const config = await import(`../../data/config.json`)
  const data = matter(content.default)

  return {
    props: {
      siteTitle: config.title,
      frontmatter: data.data,
      markdownBody: data.content,
    },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  //get all .md files in the posts dir
  const blogs = glob.sync('src/markdown/posts/**/*.md')

  //remove path and extension to leave filename only
  const blogSlugs = blogs.map(file =>
    file
      .split('/')[2]
      .replace(/ /g, '-')
      .slice(0, -3)
      .trim()
  )

  // create paths with `slug` param
  const paths = blogSlugs.map(slug => `/blog/${slug}`)
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

New Errors

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).parse is not a function
    at /home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/src/.next/server/static/F_8nzvuKI79UB0iqKIVhG/pages/blog/[slug].js:914:67
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getStaticPaths (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/src/.next/server/static/F_8nzvuKI79UB0iqKIVhG/pages/blog/[slug].js:914:27)
    at buildStaticPaths (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:18:86)
    at Object.isPageStatic (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:25:548)
    at execFunction (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:155:17)
    at execHelper (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:139:5)
    at execMethod (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:143:5)
    at process.<anonymous> (/home/mac/Documents/lucy-portfolio/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:64:7)
    at process.emit (events.js:315:20) {
  type: 'TypeError'
}
```

Code as follows

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const path = require
  //get all .md files in the posts dir
  const blogs = glob.sync('src/markdown/posts/**/*.md')

  //remove path and extension to leave filename only
  const blogSlugs = blogs.map(file => path.parse(file).name);
  // create paths with `slug` param
  const paths = blogSlugs.map(slug => `/blog/${slug}`)
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: I expect it to be a problem with the way you set the relative routes. Can you show the project file structure and the function that generates the routes from files?

Comment: That function is part of Next.js, it automatically makes a route out of all the files in the /pages directory.

Comment: @CedomirRackov I removed the node modules, if you need this let me know and I will upload the full file structure to a gist. File structure is added to original post.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade How do I fix it then? As it is appearing with that error when I try to deploy the site to Now

Comment: Thanks. Now on the page blog/[slug].js what is in the getInitialProps function?

Comment: There is no getInitialProps, there is a get StaticProps though export async function getStaticProps({ ...ctx }) {
  const { slug } = ctx.params
  const content = await import(`../../markdown/posts/${slug}.md`)
  const config = await import(`../../data/config.json`)
  const data = matter(content.default)

Comment: and export async function getStaticPaths() {
  //get all .md files in the posts dir
  const blogs = glob.sync('src/markdown/posts/**/*.md')

Comment: Looking at the file structure and the errors. Those files actually don't exist.

Comment: The error is in the way you are generating the static paths

Comment: There is most likely more to the function getStaticPaths then you pasted, can you edit the question with the full getStaticPath?

Comment: @CedomirRackov I have added the full getSaticProps and Paths sections

Comment: Found the issue. Writing the answer

Comment: @CedomirRackov amazing, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplified code. Keep the glob as is, it seems to be working fine. The issue is in how you parse the names from the list.

In this snippet you will see the issue of the `blogSlugs` from your code and the `newBlogSlugs` as a solution.

**What the `newBlogSlugs` code does?**

`file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split('.')[0]`

Replace methods replaces all the path parts except the last one and we get "cupcakes.md". Then we split the string on the dot and use only the first part and get "cupcakes".

```js
// This represent the output of your glob function. You don't nee to copy the list. That is just for clarity on how the blogs array looks.
const blogs = [
  "src/markdown/posts/cupcakes.md",
  "src/markdown/posts/cat-stuff.md"
];

// This is your blogSlugs contstant
const blogSlugs = blogs.map(file =>
  file
    .split('/')[2]
    .replace(/ /g, '-')
    .slice(0, -3)
    .trim()
)

// This is the new solution that you should use instead of your blogSlugs
// !!! UPDATED HERE
const newBlogSlugs = blogs.map(file => file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').split('.')[0]);

console.log("Original", blogSlugs);
console.log("Fixed", newBlogSlugs);
```

EDIT: Mentioned that I used path module.

EDIT2: Changed the naming of the variables so they look more like the code in question.

EDIT3: In the original answer i used the path module for getting the slug, changed it to string replace. Remove the path module, it is producing the error.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure I am understanding this, where are the changes that need to be made? As the const list doesn't exist in my code, apologies I'm still kind of new at this

Comment: No problems, let me change it up a bit.

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if you is clear now.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the code I have edited from the answer you gave, I receive different errors now about parse not being a function

Comment: That is my bad. Updating the fix

Comment: Updated the answer. Remove the path module, and instead of using path.parse, use the replace method of the string

Comment: Tried with and without path = require without I get path is not defined. With I get path.replace is not a function?

Comment: It should be file.replace. Updating the typo in the answer

Comment: I now receive the same error just on the md file instead of the folder? i.e: Error occurred prerendering page "/design/three". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Cannot find module './three.md'

Comment: Does three.md exist?

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please upvote and accept it. @MacDev

Comment: All done apologies having to work on another bug, local builds work fine now but getting errors upon pushing to Now

Comment: it's fine, I figured out how to fix the other errors it was a  Error: A routes-manifest.json couldn't be found. found a fix here: https://spectrum.chat/thread/020a6d42-94e0-4786-968e-da68f107da8e?m=MTU4NTI0NzQwMTAxMQ==